# Безопасные подходы к выгрузке данных на сайт из удаленной базы данных

Tags: php, mysql, ssh

Есть два независимых сервера, в разных ДЦ.

На первом сервере есть база данных, хранящая в себе некоторые данные (температуру датчиков, время)
На втором сервере есть веб-страница, куда я хочу выводить данные с БД первого сервера.

Столкнулся с этим впервые, экспериментом получилось открыть внешний доступ только для IP второго сервера к БД первого через 'GRANT ALL ON'. Это работает, я могу подключаться и считывать данные.

Данные не настолько секретные, но мне хотелось бы некоторого уровня безопасности внешнего подключения к БД.

В интернете одним из распространенных методов защиты я увидел SSH-туннелирование. Как я понял, это можно применить и в PHP через ssh2.

Вопросы: является ли метод SSH туннелирования хорошей практикой защиты в подобных случаях, где необходимо только выгружать данные с БД, без всяких записей? Возможно есть другие хорошие решения, более менее понятные для внедрения новичку?

Comment: Сервер, потребляющий данные, имеет же статический адрес? создайте для подключения учётную запись с указанием конкретного хоста - и можете не беспокоиться, сервер безусловно отвергнет попытку подключения с другого адреса.

Comment: Akina, спасибо за ответ! Да, у сервера статический адрес.

Comment: MySQL поддерживает TLS.

Comment: Хороший подход это организация api по верефикационным данным, токен и вы спасены. По факту .php файл обрабатывающий входящие запросы и отдающий целевые, сформированные данные по токену.